# ROWS TO COLUMNS IN SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Since I didnt frame my last question clearly Ill reframe my question -

```
Effective_date                Result_value      Elementname         Person_number       
     10-JAN-2020                    4.6             Taxable Earnings    10
     10-JUN-2020                    5               Taxable Earnings    10
     01-JAN-2020                    3.2             Basic Life          10
     10-FEB-2020                    1.6             Basic Life          10
     11-JAN-2020                    2.2             Tax Units           10       
     11-JUL-2020                    1.2             Tax Units           10
```

I have the below query  -

```
SELECT ppa.effective_date,
pra.result_value ,
pra.elementname,
prd.person_number

FROM   pay_pay_relationships_dn prd
       INNER JOIN pay_payroll_rel_actions pra
               ON prd.payroll_relationship_id = pra.payroll_relationship_id
       INNER JOIN pay_payroll_actions ppa
               ON pra.payroll_action_id = ppa.payroll_action_id
       INNER JOIN pay_all_payrolls_f pap
               ON ppa.element_type_id = pap.element_type_id
WHERE  ( and pra.elementname = 'Taxable Earnings'
         AND ppa.payroll_id = pap.payroll_id ) 
         
     This query will give a resultant as - 
     
     effective_date                result_value     elementname         person_number       
     10-JAN-2020                    4.6             Taxable Earnings    10
     10-JUN-2020                    5               Taxable Earnings    10

     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want the output like sum of the result_value if the effective_date falls between the start_date and end_date I pass. So the final query

```
     I am using is this to get the desired output-
     
     

SELECT   SUM(result_value) taxable_earn, 
         person_number 
FROM     ( 
                    SELECT     ppa.effective_date, 
                               pra.result_value , 
                               pra.elementname, 
                               prd.person_number 
                    FROM       pay_pay_relationships_dn prd 
                    inner join pay_payroll_rel_actions pra 
                    ON         prd.payroll_relationship_id = pra.payroll_relationship_id 
                    inner join pay_payroll_actions ppa 
                    ON         pra.payroll_action_id = ppa.payroll_action_id 
                    inner join pay_all_payrolls_f pap 
                    ON         ppa.element_type_id = pap.element_type_id 
                    WHERE      ( 
                               and        pra.elementname = 'Taxable Earnings' 
                               AND        ppa.payroll_id = pap.payroll_id ) 
                    AND        ppa.effective_date BETWEEN :p_start_date AND        :p_end_date )
GROUP BY person_number
     
     person_number          taxable_earn        
     10                     9.6
```

I want the output to include element names result_value for - "Basic Life", "Tax Units" to come in seperate columns in the above output-

```
      person_number     taxable_earn            Basic_Life          Tax_Units         
     10                     9.6                  4.8                    3.4
```

How can I tweak the query to get the output like above ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try below query using pivot -

```
SELECT   * 
  FROM   (SELECT     ppa.effective_date, 
                     pra.result_value , 
                     pra.elementname, 
                     prd.person_number 
            FROM     pay_pay_relationships_dn prd 
           INNER JOIN pay_payroll_rel_actions pra ON prd.payroll_relationship_id = pra.payroll_relationship_id 
           INNER JOIN pay_payroll_actions ppa ON pra.payroll_action_id = ppa.payroll_action_id 
           INNER JOIN pay_all_payrolls_f pap ON ppa.element_type_id = pap.element_type_id 
           WHERE ppa.payroll_id = pap.payroll_id
             AND ppa.effective_date BETWEEN :p_start_date AND :p_end_date)
 PIVOT    (SUM(result_value )
           FOR elementname IN ('taxable_earn' taxable_earn, 'Basic_Life' Basic_Life, 'Tax_Units' Tax_Units))
```

Comment: This did not work completely. since its been many days I raised this question I raised a seperate questio nwith my issue